# Facebook app URL scheme to a group with an id that is not a number

Tags: facebook, url-scheme

I'm trying to link to Facebook groups in the app from my website. Currently the scheme works for linking to a group with an ID that is a *string of numbers*, eg. 1808123152733889

- fb://profile/1808123152733889  (this works currently)

However some Facebook groups have an ID that is a *string of letters*, eg. EastBayBerniecrats and I haven't found a scheme that works.

I have tried:

- fb://profile/EastBayBerniecrats,
- fb://profile?id=EastBayBerniecrats,
- fb://groups/EastBayBerniecrats (takes user to list of all subscribed
  groups),

and others. I tried each with a "/" at the end and without.

Any ideas?

EDIT: turns out that it suits my purposes to search for the groups id number using a service like this: https://lookup-id.com/

Comment: That‘s not a different kind of id, but a group name - different thing. You can only use the group id here, not the group name.

Comment: Are you suggesting there is no way to get into an app directly to the group if it uses a name? The regular url is, https://www.facebook.com/groups/EastBayBerniecrats/

Comment: No, I am saying you still need to use the id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have found your group id. It's

1808123152733889

You need to use this url scheme:

group?id=[your_group_id]

So, the final link from app to facebook iOS app, should look like:

fb://group?id=1808123152733889